# *why* does multiprocessing serialize my function and closure?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

According to https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html
multiprocessing forks (for *nix) to create a worker process to execute tasks. We can verify this by setting up a global variable in a module prior to the fork. 
If the worker function imports that module and finds the variable present, then the process memory has been copied. And so it is:

```
import os

def f(x):
    import sys
    return sys._mypid  # <<< value is returned by subprocess!


def set_state():
    import sys
    sys._mypid = os.getpid()

def g():
    from multiprocessing import Pool
    pool = Pool(4)
    try:
        for z in pool.imap(f, range(1000)):
            print(z)
    finally:
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

if __name__=='__main__':
    set_state()
    g()
```

However, if things work this way, what business does multiprocessing have in serializing the work function, f?

In this example:

```
import os

def set_state():
    import sys
    sys._mypid = os.getpid()

def g():
    def f(x):
        import sys
        return sys._mypid

    from multiprocessing import Pool
    pool = Pool(4)
    try:
        for z in pool.imap(f, range(1000)):
            print(z)
    finally:
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

if __name__=='__main__':
    set_state()
    g()
```

we get:

```
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'g.<locals>.f'
```

Stackoverflow and the internet is full of ways to work around this. (Python's standard pickle function can handle functions, but not function with closure data).

But why do we get here? A copy-on-write version of `f` is in the forked process's memory. Why does it need to be serialized at all?

Comment: Never mind -- figured it out.
Its because `f` is not available when `Pool` is called and the processes are forked.

Comment: You can write an answer to your own question

Comment: @user48956: Note that it’s not a *timing* thing: `f` exists when the `Pool` is constructed, but there’s no way for it to know to squirrel away a reference to it so as to avoid needing to transmit some description of it during the `imap`.  One could imagine a “care package” of non-global objects being supplied at the time of `fork`, but since that would not help the `spawn` method it’s probably not a priority.

Comment: That’s true for spawns. Not true for forks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Derp -- it has to be this way because:

```
    pool = Pool(4)  <<< processes created here

    for z in pool.imap(f, range(1000)):   <<< reference to function
```

FYI... anyone wanting to fork, where the new process has access to the function (and thereby avoids serializing the function), can follow this pattern:

```
import collections
import multiprocessing as mp
import os
import pickle
import threading

_STATUS_DATA = 0
_STATUS_ERR = 1
_STATUS_POISON = 2


Message = collections.namedtuple(
    "Message",
    ["status",
     "payload",
     "sequence_id"
     ]
)

def parallel_map(
        target,
        args,
        num_processes,
        inq_maxsize=None,
        outq_maxsize=None,
        serialize=pickle.dumps,
        deserialize=pickle.loads,
        start_method="fork",
        preserve_order=True,
):
    """
    :param target: Target function
    :param args: Iterable of single parameter arguments for target.
    :param num_processes: Number of processes.
    :param inq_maxsize:
    :param outq_maxsize:
    :param serialize:
    :param deserialize:
    :param start_method:
    :param preserve_order: If true result are returns in the order received by args. Otherwise,
      first result is returned first
    :return:
    """
    if inq_maxsize is None: inq_maxsize=10*num_processes
    if outq_maxsize is None: outq_maxsize=10*num_processes
    inq = mp.Queue(maxsize=inq_maxsize)
    outq = mp.Queue(maxsize=outq_maxsize)
    poison = serialize(Message(_STATUS_POISON, None, -1))
    deserialize(poison) # Test

    def work():
        while True:
            obj = inq.get()
            # print("{} - GET .. OK".format(os.getpid()))
            # inq.task_done()

            try:
                msg = deserialize(obj)
                assert isinstance(msg, Message)
                if msg.status==_STATUS_POISON:
                    outq.put(serialize(Message(_STATUS_POISON,None,msg.sequence_id)))
                    # print("{} - RETURN POISON .. OK".format(os.getpid()))
                    return
                else:
                    args, kw = msg.payload
                    result = target(*args,**kw)
                    outq.put(serialize(Message(_STATUS_DATA,result,msg.sequence_id)))

            except Exception as e:
                try:
                    outq.put(serialize(Message(_STATUS_ERR,e,msg.sequence_id)))
                except Exception as e2:
                    try:
                        outq.put(serialize(Message(_STATUS_ERR,None,-1)))
                        # outq.put(serialize(1,Exception("Unable to serialize response")))
                        # TODO. Log exception
                    except Exception as e3:
                        pass

    if start_method == "thread":
        _start_method = threading.Thread
    else:
        _start_method = mp.get_context('fork').Process

    processes = [
        _start_method(
            target=work,
            name="parallel_map.work"
        )
        for _ in range(num_processes)]

    for p in processes:
        p.start()

    quitting = []
    def quit_processes():
        if not quitting:
            quitting.append(1)
        # Send poison pills - kill child processes
        for _ in range(num_processes):
            inq.put(poison)

    nsent = [0]
    def send():
        # Send the data
        for seq_id, arg in enumerate(args):
            obj = ((arg,), {})
            inq.put(serialize(Message(_STATUS_DATA, obj, seq_id)))
            nsent[0] += 1
        quit_processes()

    # Publish
    sender = threading.Thread(
        target=send,
        name="parallel_map.sender",
        daemon=True)
    sender.start()

    try:
        # Consume
        nquit = [0]
        buffer = {}
        nyielded = 0
        while True:
            result = outq.get() # Waiting here
            # outq.task_done()
            msg = deserialize(result)
            assert isinstance(msg, Message)
            if msg.status == _STATUS_POISON:
                nquit[0]+=1
                # print(">>> QUIT ACK {}".format(nquit[0]))
                if nquit[0]>=num_processes:
                    break
            else:
                assert msg.sequence_id>=0

                if preserve_order:
                    buffer[msg.sequence_id] = msg
                    while True:
                        if nyielded not in buffer:
                            break

                        msg = buffer.pop(nyielded)
                        nyielded += 1
                        if msg.status==_STATUS_ERR:
                            if isinstance(msg.payload, Exception):
                                raise msg.payload
                            else:
                                raise Exception("Unexpected exception")
                        else:
                            assert msg.status==_STATUS_DATA
                            yield msg.payload
                else:
                    if msg.status==_STATUS_ERR:
                        if isinstance(msg.payload, Exception):
                            raise msg.payload
                        else:
                            raise Exception("Unexpected exception")
                    else:
                        assert msg.status==_STATUS_DATA
                        yield msg.payload


                # if nyielded == nsent:
                #     break

    except Exception as e:
        raise
    finally:
        if not quitting:
            quit_processes()
        sender.join()
        for p in processes:
            p.join()


        def f(x):
            time.sleep(0.01)
            if x ==-1:
                raise Exception("Boo")
            return x
```

Usage:

```
        def f(x):
            time.sleep(0.01)
            if x ==-1:
                raise Exception("Boo")
            return x

        for result in parallel_map(target=f,  <<< not serialized
                                   args=range(100),
                                   num_processes=8,
                                   start_method="fork"):
            pass
```

... with that caveat: for every thread you have in your program when you fork, a puppy dies.